# "Skipped" binomial distribution sum

Tags: probability-distributions, summation

How can I show that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{N/K-1} {N \choose iK+j} p^{iK+j}(1-p)^{N-iK-j}=\frac{1}{K},$$

where $N\rightarrow \infty$, $0\le j< K$, and $K$ is finite?

Comment: You mean $0\le j<K$, right?

Comment: Thanks. Yes. When $j=K$, it seems it will go out of bound.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way is is to use the mod $K$ discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: Do you mean to use floor or ceiling functions on the upper bound of the sum? Obviously $N/K-1$ will not always be an integer.

Comment: I guess it is better to assume $N = n K$ and let $n$ go to $\infty$ instead

Comment: Couldnt solve it, had to look it up and luckily there is already a solution [$\lim_{n\to\infty}\underset{m\mid k}{\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n}} \binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k} = \frac{1}{m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284288/problem-of-limit-with-binomial-coefficients), nice problem

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it after some more thought. I am following the suggestion by kimchi lover. Let $f[n]={N \choose n} p^n (1-p)^{N-n}$ and $g[n]=\begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ if } n \mod K \equiv j \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Note that the sum is just $$\sum_{n=0}^N f[n] g[n]=\mathcal{F}(fg)[k]|_{k=0},$$ where $\mathcal{F}(f)[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f[n] e^{-i\frac{2 \pi k n }{N}}$ is the discrete Fourier transform of length-$N$. For convenience, we will use upper case letter to denote the Fourier transform. That is, $F[k] \triangleq \mathcal{F}(f)[k]$. And the inverse transform will then be given by $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(F)[n]=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} F[k] e^{i\frac{2\pi n k}{N}}$.

Now, it is easy to verify that product in Fourier domain will correspond to convolution in the original domain and vice versa. More precisely, we have 
$$ \mathcal{F}(fg)= \frac{1}{N} F \circledast G$$

Without loss of generality, we will assume $N$ is divisible by $K$ and $N=K N'$. Let's try to find $F[k]$ and $G[k]$. For $F[k]$, 
$$F[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} {N \choose n} (1-p)^{N-n} (pe^{-i\frac{2\pi k}{N}})^n = (1-p+pe^{-i\frac{2\pi k}{N}})^N.$$

For $G[k]$, first consider the case when $j=0$, let $g_0[n]=\begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ if } n \mod K \equiv 0 \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$. One can verify that $G_0[k]$ is simply 
$$ G_0[k]=\begin{cases} N' & \mbox{ if } k \mod N' \equiv 0 \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ Now for $j \neq 0$, $g[n] $ is just a shift of $g_0[n]$ by $j$ samples. Thus 
$$ G[k]=\begin{cases} N' e^{i\frac{2\pi j k}{N}}& \mbox{ if } k \mod N' \equiv 0 \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Finally, the sum is then 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}(fg)[k]|_{k=0}&= \frac{1}{N} F \circledast G[k]|_{k=0} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k'=0}^{N-1} F[k'] G[k-k']|_{k=0} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k'=0}^{N-1} F[k'] G[-k'] \\
&= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{m=0}^{K} (1-p+pe^{-i\frac{2\pi N' m }{N}})^N N' e^{-i\frac{2\pi j N' m}{N}} \\
&= \frac{1}{K} \sum_{m=0}^{K} (1-p+pe^{-i\frac{2\pi  m }{K}})^N  e^{-i\frac{2\pi j m}{K}} \\
&= \frac{1}{K}, \mbox{as $N$ goes to infinity},
\end{align*}
where the last equality is due to the fact that $(1-p+pe^{-i\frac{2\pi  m }{K}})$ has magnitude less than 1 except when $m=0$. So as $N$ goes to infinity, only the first term in the sum is non-zero.

Some final words. The scenario in this setup is analogous to sampling above Nyquist rate in digital signal processing. There is no aliasing and "copies" from higher frequency band does not mix up with the baseband.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the final observation? The "signal" you are referring to is the binomial distribution? Do you think than that there is a "finite frequency" extension of this result?

Comment: Yes. The signal here is $f[n]$, the binomial distribution. When we make periodic sampling of this length-$N$ sample (downsampled by $K$), the effect in frequency domain is that we will have $K$  identical copies of the original at  $k=0,N',2N',\cdots,KN'$. Say if $N'$ is finite, those copies will "spill" over to the zero frequency component. So the "finite frequency" extension is simply the second last sum above (we can't reduce to $\frac{1}{K}$). This "spillover" is known to be aliasing in signal processing.

Answer (score 1):

With $\binom{n}{r}=\oint\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^r}\frac{dz}{2\pi\operatorname{i}z}$ (with the centre-$O$ unit circle as the contour), the sum is$$\begin{align}&\sum_{i\ge0}\oint\frac{(1+z)^N}{z^{iK+j}}p^{iK+j}(1-p)^{N-iK-j}\frac{dz}{2\pi\operatorname{i}z}\\&=\sum_{i\ge0}\oint((1-p)(1+z))^N\left(\frac{p}{(1-p)z}\right)^{iK+j}\frac{dz}{2\pi\operatorname{i}z}\\&=\oint((1-p)(1+z))^N\left(\frac{p}{(1-p)z}\right)^j\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{p}{(1-p)z}\right)^K}\frac{dz}{2\pi\operatorname{i}z}\\&=p^j(1-p)^{N+K-j}\oint\frac{(1+z)^Nz^{K-j-1}}{(1-p)^Kz^K-p^K}\frac{dz}{2\pi\operatorname{i}}.\end{align}$$The poles are all first-order, at $\frac{p}{1-p}\exp\frac{2\pi\operatorname{i}l}{K}$ for $0\le l<K$, so the above expression is$$p^j(1-p)^{N+K-j}\sum_{l=0}^{K-1}\left.\frac{(1+z)^Nz^{-j}}{K(1-p)^K}\right|_{z=\frac{p}{1-p}\exp\frac{2\pi\operatorname{i}l}{K}}\\=\frac1K\sum_l\frac{\left(1-p+p\exp\frac{2\pi\operatorname{i}l}{K}\right)^N}{\exp\frac{2\pi\operatorname{i}jl}{K}}.$$In the $N\to\infty$ limit only $l=0$ survives, making the sum $1$.